RabbitMQ Consumer goes down
Using rabbitMQ 3.8.2 and erlang 22.2.7, I tried to upload 3mb video file as base64 format through API, now the consumer is getting lost, queue is in ready stage always because of this, further I'm not able to call another API with that queue, if I didn't call the upload API then other APIs working fine with the same queue and consumer. There is no message size limit on rabbitMQ side, I have checked rabbitMQ logs didn't get exact root cause, what might be the possibilities.
